# Algebra-precalculus question based on maximum, minimum and the average functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x) = \max(2 − 3x, x + 2) , -\infty ≤ x ≤ + \infty$$

$$g(x) = \min(2 − 3x, x + 2) , -\infty ≤ x ≤ + \infty$$

$$h(x) = \mathrm{avg}(f(x), g(x)) , −\infty  ≤ x ≤ + \infty$$

If $f(x) = g(x) = h(x)$, then find the value of $x$.

On seeing the graph:

Maximum value of $f(x)$ is $+\infty$.

Minimum value of $g(x)$ is $-\infty$

But answer is $0$. How?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misinterpreting what $f,g$ mean. Given any particular fixed $x,$ $f(x)$ is defined to be the maximum value of $2-3x$ and $x+2,$ while $g(x)$ is defined to be the minimum of these two numbers. There are a few ways we can proceed. One is to draw the graphs of $y=3-2x$ and $y=x+2,$ and use these to find the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x),$ and from there find the graph of $y=h(x):=\frac{f(x)+g(x)}2.$

We could also use a formulaic approach. Given any real numbers $a,b$ we can show that $$\max(a,b)=\frac{a+b+|b-a|}2$$ and $$\min(a,b)=\frac{a+b-|b-a|}2.$$ Consequently, letting $a=3-2x$ and $b=x+2,$ we get $$f(x)=\frac{4-2x+|4x|}2=\frac{4-2x+4|x|}2=2-x+2|x|,$$ and similarly, $$g(x)=2-x-2|x|,$$ whence $$h(x)={f(x)+g(x)}2=\frac{4-2x}2=2-x.$$ At that point, we need to find $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)=h(x).$ Since $f(x)=h(x)+2|x|$ and $g(x)=h(x)-2|x|,$ then we readily see that $f(x)=g(x)=h(x)$ if and only if $x=0.$

Alternately, we can note that for $a\neq b,$ we necessarily have $\max(a,b)\ne\min(a,b).$ Consequently, $f(x)\neq g(x)$ if $2-3x\ne x+2$--*i.e.*: if $x\neq 0.$ On the other hand, $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ are both readily equal to $2,$ so $h(0)$ is, as well, and so $x=0$ is the desired solution.

Comment: f(x)=max(2−3x,x+2) since x+2 has an increasing slope hence it will be maximum. f(x)= x+2. Am I right? @CameronBuie

Comment: I'm afraid that's not true in general. Consider what happens when $x=-1,$ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two numbers $a,b$, you always have $\min(a,b)\leq \frac{a+b}{2} \leq \max(a,b)$ with equalities if and only if $a=b$.

In this case, you have $a=2-3x$ and $b=x+2$ and you want find $x$ to have equalities, so you need to have $x$ such that $2-3x=x+2$ or $x=0$.

Comment: But, am I doing it wrong? On seeing the graph? @Batman

Comment: @mathematics - yes, you're trying to find the point $x$ where $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ all the same. If you plot $f(x), g(x), h(x)$, you'll see that happens at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You took it incorrectly if its given that $t(x)=max/min(f(x),g(x))$ then it means that we take that function which attains maximum or minimum at that point ie at that particular value of $x$ for eg if we take $f(x)=max(x,x^2)$ that means $f(x) $is defined as $x^2$ for $x \in (-\infty,0)$ ,$f(x)=x$ for $x\in(0,1)$,$f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in(1,\infty)$.Hope you can handle it now.